# Derecursing this specific JS function

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree

I wrote the following recursive JS function that takes a single parameter `node` which is made of other nodes and modifies it by adding to each node its number of **leaves** (not only direct children) :

```
const addWidths = (node) => {
    const keys = Object.keys(node)
    for(const key of keys){
        addWidths(node[key])
    }
    if(keys.length > 0){
        node["width"] = Object.values(node).reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur["width"], 0)
    }else{
        node["width"] = 1
    }
}
```

Here's an example of the `node` parameter :

```
const object = {
    "A": {
        "1": {},
        "2": {
            "+": {},
            "-": {}
        },
        "3": {}
    },
    "B": {
        "1": {}
    },
    "C": {},
    "D": {}
}
```

`addWidth(object)` would modify it and turn it into :

```
{
    "A": {
        "1": {
            "width": 1
        },
        "2": {
            "+": {
                "width": 1
            },
            "-": {
                "width": 1
            },
            "width": 2
        },
        "3": {
            "width": 1
        },
        "width": 4
    },
    "B": {
        "1": {
            "width": 1
        },
        "width": 1
    },
    "C": {
        "width": 1
    },
    "D": {
        "width": 1
    },
    "width":7
}
```

I need help to **make my function iterative**.

EDIT: Here's a drawing of the modified tree with the expected widths of each node :

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the desired output: the **leaves** of the tree have **no** children, yet still 1 is counted. This seems to suggest that the node itself is counted as well, but this is not consistent with how the count looks for non-leaves. I'm quite sure I am counting 10 nodes in your tree in total (or 11 if the top-level object is counted as well -- just count the number of opening braces), yet the top-level object gets a `width` value of 7. You've lost me there. Are you only counting leaf-nodes? There are indeed just 7 among the 11 nodes that are leaves. Can you clarify?

Comment: I added a small drawing at the end of my question, hope that makes it more clear.

Comment: So, yes, that confirms my suspicion that you are not counting all children (as you write in your post), but only count **leaves**. Can you update your question? You'll agree that the image depicts a tree with 12 nodes, but only 6 leaves, and it is the latter that you are counting.

Comment: You're right I'm doing it now. I had a hard time writting this part of my question and it doesn't surprise me that I miswrote it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your intent is to only count *leaves* in the tree, not internal nodes.

Your recursive implementation can be written without recursion by using an explicit stack to mimic what the recursive implementation does:

```js
const addWidths = (node) => {
    const stack = [[node, Object.values(node)]];
    while (stack.length) {
        const [node, nonvisited] = stack.at(-1);
        if (nonvisited.length == 0) {
            stack.pop();
            node.width = Object.values(node)
                        .reduce((sum, {width}) => sum + width, 0) || 1;
        } else {
            const child = nonvisited.pop();
            stack.push([child, Object.values(child)]);
        }
    }
}

const object = {
    "A": {
        "1": {},
        "2": {
            "+": {},
            "-": {}
        },
        "3": {}
    },
    "B": {
        "1": {}
    },
    "C": {},
    "D": {}
}
addWidths(object);
console.log(object);
```

Here is a variant that has a more flat stack structure:

```js
const addWidths = (node) => {
    const stack = [node];
    while (stack.length) {
        const node = stack.pop();
        const children = Object.values(node);
        if (children.length && !children[0].width) {
            stack.push(node, ...children);
        } else {
            node.width = children.reduce((sum, {width}) => sum + width, 0) || 1;
        }
    }
}

const object = {
    "A": {
        "1": {},
        "2": {
            "+": {},
            "-": {}
        },
        "3": {}
    },
    "B": {
        "1": {}
    },
    "C": {},
    "D": {}
}
addWidths(object);
console.log(object);
```

Comment: Thank you that's what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you could take a single loop iteration for every object in standard recursive approach.

```js
const addWidths = node => {
    let width = 0;
    for (const key in node) width += addWidths(node[key]);
    node.width = width || 1;
    return node.width;
};

const object = { A: { 1: {}, 2: { "+": {}, "-": {} },  3: {} }, B: { 1: {} }, C: {}, D: {} } ;

addWidths(object);
console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Now the converted approach by using an iterative approach with a stack, where the node and the parent nodes are stored.

```js
const addWidths = node => {
    const stack = [[node, []]];
  
    while (stack.length) {
        const [node, parents] = stack.pop();
        let hasChildren = false;
        for (const key in node)  {
            stack.push([node[key], [...parents, node]]);
            hasChildren = true;
        }
        if (!hasChildren) {
            for (const parent of parents) parent.width = (parent.width || 0) + 1;
            node.width = 1;
        }
    }
}

const object = { A: { 1: {}, 2: { "+": {}, "-": {} },  3: {} }, B: { 1: {} }, C: {}, D: {} } ;

addWidths(object);
console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```